# Apps Script: Getting a range of columns without taking into account rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that links to a Google Form and on each response the information is directed to the relevant team by email.

Recently, a VLookup was added to the sheet (in the end column) which has thrown off the script as it currently displays a "N/A" error (which will remain until the linked sheet has information added to it).

I am trying to limit the number of columns that the script looks at, in the hopes that this error will no longer affect the running of my script - however I'm not sure of the best way to enter the range...nothing seems to be working.  This is what I currently have, where EM is the last column that my form data is in before the vlookup...

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
var range = sheet.getDataRange("A:EM");
var values = range.getValues();
var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
var lastRowValues = values[lastRow-1];
Logger.log(lastRowValues);
```

I have tried adding A1:EM but that doesn't seem to work either so I assume I am using the wrong "get"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
var lastRowValues = values[lastRow-1];
Logger.log(lastRowValues);
```

**Explanation:**

You have two options:

- Use `getDataRange()` with no parameters:

  ```
  sheet.getDataRange();
  ```
- Or use `getRange("A:EM")` to specify the exact range:

  ```
  sheet.getRange("A:EM");
  ```

**References:**

- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

Comment: Thanks so much - that really helps!  For some reason the script still isn't working, even though it was working perfectly before the vlookup was entered so I think it's back to the drawing board but I really appreciate your help because I've learnt something new!

Answer (score 0):

getDataRange() does not require parameters

Try this instead:

```
function myfun() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet0");
var range = sheet.getRange("A:EM");
var values = range.getValues();
var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
var lastRowValues = values[lastRow-1];
Logger.log(lastRowValues);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that really helps!  For some reason the script still isn't working, even though it was working perfectly before the vlookup was entered so I think it's back to the drawing board but I really appreciate your help because I've learnt something new!